# Pandas - Lookup date in another DF, if no date available then

Tags: pandas

**DF1 **

| Unique IDs | Task | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Track | 28/05/2018 | 28/05/2018 |
| 455 | Expire |  | 07/02/2018 |
| 986 | Sell | 05/01/2020 | 28/05/2018 |

**DF2 **

| Unique IDs |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 455 |
| 986 |

What I'd like to do is, look up the unique ID from **DF2** and get the **Date 1** that corresponds to the "Track" Task. If the Track task is empty then take the Date 2.

**Desired Output**

| Unique IDs | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 28/05/2018 |
| 455 | 07/02/2018 |
| 986 | 05/01/2020 |

Ideally I would like an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a mask, to know if Date1 is nan or not and then set `date` column of `df2` either with `date1` values or `date2` values.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [123, 455, 986],
                    "task": ["Track", "Expire", "Sell"],
                    "date1": [pd.Timestamp("28/05/2018"), np.nan, pd.Timestamp("05/01/2020")],
                    "date2": [pd.Timestamp("28/05/2018"), pd.Timestamp("07/02/2018"), pd.Timestamp("28/05/2018")]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [123, 455, 986]})

mask = df1.loc[:, "date1"].notna()
df2.loc[mask, "date"] = df1.loc[mask, "date1"]
df2.loc[~mask, "date"] = df1.loc[~mask, "date2"]
print(df2)
```

```
   id       date
0  123 2018-05-28
1  455 2018-07-02
2  986 2020-05-01
```